# PHP Mod_rewrite and URL-encoded symbols - only can use either of them but not both?

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, request, urlencode

The mod_rewrite seems to convert the symbol of plus before I get it into $_REQUEST, and I don't know what to fix it...

```
RewriteRule ^invite/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\+\/]+)/?$   invite.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

For instance, I input this into my URL,

```
http://mywebsite/invite/xPo8lUEXpqg8bKL%2B32o6yIOK
```

i get this,

```
xPo8lUEXpqg8bKL 32o6yIOK
```

but if I input this request without passing through the mod_rewrite,

```
http://mywebsite/invite.php?key=xPo8lUEXpqg8bKL%2B32o6yIOK
```

i get this what I want,

```
xPo8lUEXpqg8bKL+32o6yIOK
```

What can I do? Or is it that I only can use either them but not both??

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you input, and what you get?

Comment: @Pekka: sorry I just corrected my mistakes in my writing above and have clarified my inputs. Thanks.

Comment: +1 interesting question - have never come across this before.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the [B] flag (escape backreferences):

```
RewriteRule ^invite/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\+\/]+)/?$   invite.php?key=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

The "+" character is reserved in the query string part of an URL as a space. Actually, "+" status as a reserved character is documented in [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and its (now legacy) use as a space replacement character is documented in [rfc1630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630).

Since Apache tries to avoid any conflict, it automatically escapes "+" as a string before passing it over.

---

Using the `[NE] (NoEscape)` flag on your rewrite should prevent that behavior from happening.

```
RewriteRule ^invite/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\+\/]+)/?$   invite.php?key=$1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

However, by using this, unescaped "+" WILL be replaced by a space if the user types the URL manually. To be on the safe side, simply replace all spaces in your input by "+" signs.

---

**Quite frankly**, since you do not accept spaces in your input, simply replace all spaces with a "+" symbol. Using the `[NE]` flag can bring out bigger issues then a simple character substitution. A simple `$_GET['key'] = str_replace($_GET['key'], ' ', '+');` should suffice.

Comment: thanks for this. I just tried but still no luck... any other options please...?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Since you do not accept spaces in your input, a simple `$_GET['key'] = str_replace($_GET['key'], ' ', '+');` should suffice. It will be your only source of spaces anyway.